# Upload image through form post

Tags: c#, post, asp.net-web-api, multipartform-data

I'm trying to upload an image through a `multipart/form-data` post and I'm using the code below. I'm only going to be uploading `.jpg` images.

The problem is that the image that is saved is not a valid image and it can't be viewed. It's also 200 bytes larger than the file I'm uploading so I assume I'm missing something here?

```
public class FileUploadController : ApiController
{
    public Task<HttpResponseMessage> PostUploadFile()
    {
        return UploadFileAsync().ContinueWith<HttpResponseMessage>((tsk) =>
            {
                HttpResponseMessage response = null;

                if (tsk.IsCompleted)
                {
                    response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Created);
                }
                else if (tsk.IsFaulted || tsk.IsCanceled)
                {
                   response = 
                   new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError);
                }

                return response;
            });
    }

    public Task UploadFileAsync()
    {
        return this.Request.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().ContinueWith((tsk) => 
        { SaveToFile(tsk.Result); },
        TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion);
    }

    private void SaveToFile(Stream requestStream)
    {
        string path =
        System.IO.Path.Combine(System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory);
        using (FileStream targetStream = 
        File.Create(path + "/Uploads/" + DateTime.Now.ToFileTime() + ".jpg"))
        {
            using (requestStream)
            {
                requestStream.CopyTo(targetStream);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here's a simple form I'm using to post the image.

```
<form action="/api/postuploadfile" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
    Upload Image:
    <input type="file" id="imagename" name="imagename" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

**Info about the image, before/after:**
If I check the properties of the image I've uploaded then the **Size on disk** is the same as the original image, but the **Size** property is 200-205 bytes larger. That's always the case, no matter how large the image is I upload.

Here's part of the POST headers. I don't need to strip out the *boundary* part or anything?

```
Source
-----------------------------1944294225892 Content-Disposition: form-data;
name="imagename"; filename="small.jpg" Content-Type: image/jpeg
```

And some more headers...

```
Request Headers From Upload Stream
Content-Length  125661
Content-Type    multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------1944294225892
```

Comment: Looks ok to me, encoding issue perhaps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually you will need to parse the `requestStream` with some kind of **multipart parser** as discussed here in order to strip off the header:

- [Reading file input from a multipart/form-data POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7460088/reading-file-input-from-a-multipart-form-data-post),
- [Are there any multipart/form-data parser in C# - (NO ASP)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3880530/are-there-any-multipart-form-data-parser-in-c-sharp-no-asp)

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you! I included the open source code from the second link and it worked.