# How to append objects in FormData in javascript?

Tags: javascript, c#, xmlhttprequest, multipartform-data, form-data

We need to send the data to the server by appending it within formdata in javascript. In javascript, we have handle this as like below.

```
var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
ajax.open("POST", url, true);
var formData = new FormData();
var obj = {url: "uploadUrl",type: 'POST', mode: true};
formData.append('myData', JSON.stringify(obj));
ajax.send(formData);
```

In server end, we have the method as like below.

```
 public void Save(MyModel args) {
     ....
    }


    public class MyModel
    {

        public MyObj myData { get; set; }

    }
    public class MyObj
    {
        public string url { get; set; }
        public string type { get; set; }
        public bool mode { get; set; }
    }
```

args.myData always received as null. How to receive the data sent from the client here in this format ? Suggest your ideas.

Comment: append each key/value pair

Comment: From the code provided you don't attach the form data to the xmlhttprequest object.

Comment: @Dimitar, I missed to mention that, but that is not the issue in our side.

Comment: Your `ajax.open` still looks wrong (see my answer): is this just another mistake here? Did you inspect your network traffic to see if the problem is on the client or on the server side?

Comment: @KarthikRavichandran and you have missed what you have as "server side". MVC, Web Api, something else ? Please provide all the necessary infomation, so people can help you.

Comment: I have used MVC in my side

Answer (score 2):

You need to explicitly send the `formData`:

```js
var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
ajax.open('POST', url, true);
var formData = new FormData();
var obj = {url: "uploadUrl",type: 'POST', mode: true};
formData.append('myData', obj);
ajax.send(formData);
```

(Note that I fixed the arg order in `ajax.open` and the received formdata will be something like `[object Object]` but I think `JSON.stringify()` should be the solution here - that depends on how your server parses the formdata)

Answer (score 1):

In server code, set the type of args to String and check if you are getting the stringified data.
If you are getting it, parse the data accordingly to fit into MyModel.

Providing more info of Server code might help me to look into further.

**EDIT 1: Links that might also help**

- [Reading file input from a multipart/form-data POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7460088/reading-file-input-from-a-multipart-form-data-post/17837515)
- [Are there any multipart/form-data parser in C# - (NO ASP)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3880530/are-there-any-multipart-form-data-parser-in-c-sharp-no-asp)

Comment: If we set the argument type as string it receives properly. shall we changed the type with strongly defined class instead of string? because multiple data will be sent to server

Comment: Can you provide the args (string data).

Comment: Please check the attached links which might help you.