# C# - How to parse http header multipart

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, wcf-data-services

I created a WCF Rest service and I am reading content sent by multipart/form data. However I get the contentdisposition and extra information. Is there a way to parse it like using HttpContext. I dont want dependency with asp...

If possible no use of external libraries, thirdparty dlls, etc... Unless its simple and consistent code I can implement.

Comment: This is just a stab in the dark, but have you tried this: `OperationContext.Current.IncomingMessageHeaders`.

Comment: No, but I tried HttpContext.Current.Request.Params["file"]; and I know it works but it creates dependency with IIS.

Comment: If the payload is an OData message (guessing from you tagging this as WCF Data Services), you could use ODataLib to parse it for you...

Comment: @VitekKarasMSFT Its just a file I attached. multipart/form-data

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7460088/reading-file-input-from-a-multipart-form-data-post/21689347#21689347

Comment: @OhadSchneider I'll try it ! because the one below has a bug...

Comment: Good luck! Works well for me so far

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case of parsing multipart data you should use some library/class or do it manually. There is no built-in functionality. Parser is pretty easy. But you can reuse some parser classes already written.

1. Try following project (MIT license) and file HttpMultipartParser.cs from this project:

   https://bitbucket.org/lorenzopolidori/http-form-parser/src
2. http://multipartparser.codeplex.com/

   http://multipartparser.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/69709#458003