# Send image as stream from WP8 to WCF with REST, without "header"

Tags: c#, wcf, rest, windows-phone-8

I have the connection working between my WP8 and WFC, I can send a picture as stream(byte-array)

Service side

```
[OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "FileUpload/{fileName}")]
    string SendImageToDB(string fileName, Stream fileStream);
```

SendImageToDB

```
public void SendSteamToDB(byte[] stream)
    {
        MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(MyconSQL);
        MySqlCommand cmd;
        connection.Open();

        try
        {
        cmd = connection.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE PIC SET pic_link=@image WHERE id = '1';";
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@image", MySqlDbType.Blob).Value = stream;
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (MySqlException ex)
        {
            Console.Write("Error: {0}", ex.ToString());
        }
        finally
        {
            if (connection != null)
            {
                connection.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

The windows phone side

```
private void Upload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string imageID = "test";
        var client = new RestClient("http://192.168.1.130:53715//Service1.svc");
        var request = new RestRequest("FileUpload/{imageName}", Method.POST);
        request.AddUrlSegment("imageName", imageID);
        request.AddFile("image/jpeg", myImage, imageID);

        client.ExecuteAsync(request, response =>
        {
        });
        try
        {
            client.ExecuteAsync(request, response =>
            {
                if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Upload succes!");
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(response.StatusCode.ToString());
                    MessageBox.Show("Upload error!");
                }
            });
        }
        catch (Exception error)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("error" + error);
        }   
     }
```

All this is working fine, there is just one problem the byte-array I put into the database have some kind of 'header'

did put the byte array in a .txt

[image]

What is the best way to avoid this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7460088/reading-file-input-from-a-multipart-form-data-post the answer here show how to decode that format.