# How to use RestRequest/RestResponse when the web service produces multipart form data in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, restsharp

I have a web service in a RESTful web server (java) which consumes media of type APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED and produces media of type MULTIPART_FORM_DATA. Now I'm working on a REST client (C#) and trying to use this web service. I'm using **RestSharp** as the REST client. My code goes as follows:

```
RestRequest request = new RestRequest("getDataFileChunkIS", Method.POST);
request.AddParameter("sessionId", sessionId);
request.AddParameter("dataFileId", dataFileId);            
request.AddParameter("offset", offset);
request.AddParameter("chunkSize", chunkSize);
request.AddParameter("checksumFlag", checksumFlag);

RestClient client = new RestClient(url);    
RestResponse response = (RestResponse)client.Execute(request);
```

But in this response I'm getting **HTTP Status 406 - Not Acceptable**. It says "The resource identified by this request is only capable of generating responses with characteristics not acceptable according to the request "accept" headers." Maybe I'm doing it in a wrong way. So my question is that how can I execute this request whose response will contain **MULTIPART_FORM_DATA** ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) how can I execute this request whose response will contain MULTIPART_FORM_DATA?

```
request.AddHeader("Accept", "multipart/form-data")
```

2) how can I read this response header(contains JSON) using RestClient?

See answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7460088/reading-file-input-from-a-multipart-form-data-post). Particularly the third one, which shows how to do it just with .NET 4.5 libraries.

You may need to implement `IDeserializer` to get access to the raw HttpResponse for consumption.