# C# How to receive file sent from web browser

Tags: c#

I am writing one program receives data files from the web browser.

HTML code:

```html
<form action="http://192.168.0.102:8080/sync/uploadfile" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
&nbsp; <input type="submit" value="Upload File"><br />
</form>
```

Data received:

```
------WebKitFormBoundarysKV9CFx7LDIr5T1A
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="uploadFile"; filename="icon.png"
Content-Type: image/png
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
------WebKitFormBoundarysKV9CFx7LDIr5T1A--
```

I'm having problems when processing the data submitted from the browser.
I want to convert the data to file.

Please help me how to solve problem.

Comment: How are you receiving? ASP.NET? A socket?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reading file input from a multipart/form-data POST](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7460088/reading-file-input-from-a-multipart-form-data-post)

Answer (score 0):

when you receive the data as a string you could just call [File.WriteAllText("Path","Data");](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms143375(v=vs.110).aspx)

Edit:

Please see this StackOverflow post:

[How do I save a stream to a file in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/411592/how-do-i-save-a-stream-to-a-file)

Comment: Sorry, i have a  StreamReader postData.
i'm using postData.ReadToEnd() for read data.