# Grape vine: How to Parse Form Data

Tags: c#, .net, grapevine

Is there a way to correctly parse Form Data? I have a form that accepts one file and I'm unable to parse and save the file effectively although I can do it easily on an ASP.NET API

For more context, I saw this response and tried to do the same without success. Must be because it's old.
scottoffen/grapevine-legacy#193

I also checked this issue with no success [File upload example for grapevine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40254544/file-upload-example-for-grapevine)

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do this using the glorious [HttpMultipartParser](https://www.nuget.org/packages/HttpMultipartParser/) library. The source code and documentation are available on [GitHub](https://github.com/Http-Multipart-Data-Parser/Http-Multipart-Data-Parser). Here is a sample route using Grapevine 5.0.0-rc.9:

```cs
[RestRoute("Post", "/submit-form")]
[Header("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data")]
public async Task ParseMultipartFormData(IHttpContext context)
{
    var content = await MultipartFormDataParser.ParseAsync(context.Request.InputStream, context.Request.MultipartBoundary, context.Request.ContentEncoding);
    var name = $"{content.GetParameterValue("FirstName")} {content.GetParameterValue("LastName")} : {content.Files.Count}";
    await context.Response.SendResponseAsync(name);
}
```

> The header filter on `Content-Type` is optional, but it does ensure that this route doesn't get called unless there is actually multipart form data to parse.

Use Postman or some other tool, and pass `FirstName`, `LastName`, and one or more files, it will return the concatenated name and count of the files submitted. Put a breakpoint before the response is written and you can inspect the value of `content` to see how to get at the file information. Writing the files to disk should be easy to do at that point.

###### IMPORTANT

The input stream on the request can only be read once! If you want this data to be available to other requests, add it to `context.Locals`, or, better yet, use the following middleware to do that for you automatically!

```cs
public static class MultiPartFormData
{
    public async static Task Parse(IHttpContext context, IRestServer server)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(request.ContentType) || !request.ContentType.StartsWith("multipart/form-data; boundary=")) return;
        context.Locals.TryAdd("FormData", await MultipartFormDataParser.ParseAsync(context.Request.InputStream, context.Request.MultipartBoundary, context.Request.ContentEncoding));
    }

    public static IRestServer AutoParseMultipartFormData(this IRestServer server)
    {
        server.OnRequestAsync -= MultiPartFormData.Parse;
        server.OnRequestAsync += MultiPartFormData.Parse;
        return server;
    }
}
```

Then when configuring your server, you can make a simple call to `server.AutoParseMultipartFormData()`, and the data will be available to you in all of your routes if it exists, without you having to parse it explicitly.