# How can I decode a multipart HTTP response?

Tags: http, c#-4.0, web-applications, multipart

I have an ASP.NET web application that's returning a multi-part response containing a JSON-encoded object, plus a bunch of binary files. (For the code that produces this, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/12334553/98422 - that question also gives a bit of background).

The HTTP response data looks like this:

```
--b621907a-a740-44f4-b495-a91a078b90ef
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8

[1,2]

--b621907a-a740-44f4-b495-a91a078b90ef
Content-Type: image/jpeg

<image file content>

--b621907a-a740-44f4-b495-a91a078b90ef
Content-Type: text/plain

<text file content>

--b621907a-a740-44f4-b495-a91a078b90ef--
```

So, I now want to consume the response at the client end. My client is a C# application.

How can I do this? I assume that there must be some framework support for it, but I'm not sure where to start looking.

It probably isn't relevant, but I'm using RestSharp for the bulk of my interaction with the web server. So far as I can tell, RestSharp would not be able to process this response (which is fair enough - it's not very RESTy).

What options do I have?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3880530/are-there-any-multipart-form-data-parser-in-c-sharp-no-asp